# Button to PDF on HTML

Tags: html, pdf, button

Is there any way to make a button linked to a document (PDF) on HTML?

As additional data, this button would be an image.

PS: I am using Notepad++.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to make a link? How to make an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Simply use a regular link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/myPDF.pdf">
    <img src="http://example.com/myImage.jpg">
</a>
```

And if you want it to open in a new window as to not divert traffic...

```
<a href="http://example.com/myPDF.pdf" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://example.com/myImage.jpg">
</a>
```

Also, I should mention that the text editor you use is irrelevant in this question, because Notepad++ is just want you use to write the HTML. It's not specific to any one editor.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
<a href="yourPdf.pdf"><img src="yourImage.jpg"></img></a>
```

And yes this also works with Notepad++ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button-looking image foo.png and the PDF document has the URL hyps.pdf and the title “Hypsology”, you can use a link like the following:

```
<a href="hyps.pdf"><img alt="Hypsology (PDF)" src="foo.png"></a>
```

What happens when a user clicks on the image depends on his browser and its settings.